# Why does text-overflow not function with a div in a grid?

Tags: css, css-grid

I was trying to make my design responsive by making it so that when the screen gets smaller in width, the text should be 'cut off' by three dots. However, this does not seem to function in my situation, as the .container element just seems to overflow into the main element, instead of the text getting smaller. How could I fix this? Thanks in advance!

```
<main>
    <div class="container">
        <section class="account-section">
                    <h5 class="username">WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW</h5>
        </section>
    </div>
</main>

<style>
main {
        height: 200px;
        display: grid;
        place-items: center;
        padding: 50px;
    }

    .container {
        position: relative;
        display: grid;
        grid-template: fit-content(100%) / 100%;
        max-width: 1240px;
        width: 100%;
        position: relative;
    }

    .account-section {
        height: fit-content;
    background: var(--white);
        box-shadow: 0 0 50px rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
        padding: 25px;
        position: relative;
        flex-shrink: 1;
    }

    .username {
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
        white-space: nowrap;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`overflow` in this context means, that the content cannot fit in the container and so *overflows*. Here the container is the `<h5>`, while the content is the text. The `<h5>` will just grow according to the text content by default, because it's not constrained, neither by rules set to itself nor by rules for the parent.

If you put a `width: 20%` on the `<h5>` as demonstrated below for example, the text would overflow, and the `text-overflow: ellipsis` kicks in.

Another option would be to add `overflow: hidden` to the parent with class .account-section

Just click on the `Run code snippet` button, and you'll see.

```css
main {
        height: 200px;
        display: grid;
        place-items: center;
        padding: 50px;
    }

    .container {
        position: relative;
        display: grid;
        grid-template: fit-content(100%) / 100%;
        max-width: 1240px;
        width: 100%;
        position: relative;
    }

    .account-section {
        height: fit-content;
    background: var(--white);
        box-shadow: 0 0 50px rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
        padding: 25px;
        position: relative;
        flex-shrink: 1;
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    .username {
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
        white-space: nowrap;
        overflow: hidden;
        width: 20%;
    }
    
    .username-fullwidth {
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
        white-space: nowrap;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
```

```html
<main>
    <div class="container">
        <section class="account-section">
                    <h5 class="username">WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW</h5>
        </section>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <section class="account-section">
                  <h5 class="username-fullwidth">WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWw</h5>  
        </section>
    </div>
</main>
```

Comment: Sorry, I have to clarify something. The username has to stretch out to fill up the parent container (.account_section) for design purposes. In this case, using width: 20% wouldnt work. Ive tried using width 100% but that obviously doesnt work either since it wont be restricted that way either. So basically, when the viewport gets smaller (so when main gets smaller) I want the .account-section component to shrink in size by making the text smaller. Hope this helps to clear up my needs!

Comment: So in which case should the text in the <h5> container be shortened?

Comment: The h5 heading should be shortened when the viewport is too small to contain the .container component. Right now .container overflows into main, but instead of that happening I want the text to be shortened.

Comment: Check out the answer again. I added a second variant. Should it look like that? It was achieved with an `overflow: hidden` on the parent container with class `.account-section`

Comment: Second option works. Thanks!